# Use value from yml file in non string annotation field spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use configuration value in annotation field, field is not string. For example i have:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@transactionIndexName}", shards = 1, 
refreshInterval = "2s", versionType = VersionType.EXTERNAL)
```

So in `indexName` i used spring spel, but shards is short type value, so how can i use here setting from yml file?

Comment: Or how to set shards in spring-data elasticsearch client in other place than @Document annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert your `shards` value from a `String` to a `short` within a Spel expression with something like this:

`#{T(java.lang.Short).parseShort(${transaction.shards})}`

... assuming that your property is `transaction.shards` of course.

I'm not able to test this at the moment, but I believe that should work.

Comment: It would be helpful, but this annotation is springdata's - so i can't use spel string in this field.